# Can't reach server, React 404 error 'Post'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mern

I can't reach server side I checked everything it should work
error is:
"POST http://localhost:3000/ 404 (Not Found)"

Here is my code

On client side here, I call createPost at jsx file and in actions/post.js file:

```
import * as api from "../api/index";  
import * as types from "./types";

export const createPost = (post) => async (dispatch) =>{
    try {
        const {data} = await api.createPost(post);
        dispatch({
            type: types.CREATE_POST,
            payload: data,
        });

    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
};
```

from here it should call the api,

```
import axios from "axios";
const apiEndpoint = "/";

export const fetchPosts = async () => await axios.get(apiEndpoint);
export const createPost = async (post) => await axios.post(apiEndpoint, post);
```

and from there to server side but there is a error at createPost first.

btw in server,

```
import express from "express";
import {getPosts, createPost} from "../contollers/posts.js";


const router = express.Router();

//localhost/posts
// GET POST DELETE UPDATE

router.get("/", getPosts);
router.post("/", createPost);

export default router;
```

and in controller:

```
export const createPost = async(req,res) => {
const post = req.body;
const newPost = new Post(req.body);
try{
    await newPost.save();
    res.status(201).json(newPost);
}catch(error){
    res.status(409).json({
        message: error.message,
    });
}
```

};

thanks for help

Comment: You're making a request to `/` which would be your front-end, not API. What port is your API service listening on?

Comment: listening on 3000

Comment: How are you serving your React app then? Also, where are you registering `router` with your Express app?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

yeah its my stupidity that correcting some router&dom versions and url to 5000(which is the server) solved the issue